# Consider 5 points on the surface of a sphere with radius 1. Let d be the minimum distance between 2 points.

Tags: geometry

Consider 5 points on the surface of a sphere with radius 1. Let d be the minimum distance between 2 points. How to find the maximum value of d? Is there a sipmle way?

Comment: Is $d$ Euclidean or on R^2?

Comment: This is equivalent to the $n = 5$ [Tammes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tammes_problem). Tammes has shown $d_5 = \frac{\pi}{2}$ (I assume your $d$ refer to geodesic distance on sphere).